# How to install the latest PyTorch preview (nightly) build via Poetry

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, python-poetry, package-management

The latest preview build supports [accelerated training on M1 MacBook Pros](https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-accelerated-pytorch-training-on-mac/). This feature is currently only supported by the newest preview (nightly) build:

> To get started, just install the latest Preview (Nightly) build on
> your Apple silicon Mac running macOS 12.3 or later with a native
> version (arm64) of Python.

According to [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/), this is how to install the latest preview build via `pip`:

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

But I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org) to manage my Python project dependencies.

It doesn't seem like Poetry supports the `--pre` option:

```
$ poetry add --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu 

  Stack trace:

  11  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/console_application.py:123 in run
      io = io_factory(

  10  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/console/config/application_config.py:221 in create_io
      resolved_command = application.resolve_command(args)

   9  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/console_application.py:110 in resolve_command
      return self._config.command_resolver.resolve(args, self)

   8  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/resolver/default_resolver.py:34 in resolve
      return self.create_resolved_command(result)

   7  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/resolver/default_resolver.py:166 in create_resolved_command
      if not result.is_parsable():

   6  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/resolver/resolve_result.py:43 in is_parsable
      self._parse()

   5  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/resolver/resolve_result.py:49 in _parse
      self._parsed_args = self._command.parse(self._raw_args)

   4  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/api/command/command.py:113 in parse
      return self._config.args_parser.parse(args, self._args_format, lenient)

   3  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:53 in parse
      self._parse(args, _fmt, lenient)

   2  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:101 in _parse
      self._parse_long_option(token, tokens, fmt, lenient)

   1  ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:247 in _parse_long_option
      self._add_long_option(name, None, tokens, fmt, lenient)

  NoSuchOptionException

  The "--pre" option does not exist.

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/clikit/args/default_args_parser.py:300 in _add_long_option
      296│     def _add_long_option(
      297│         self, name, value, tokens, fmt, lenient
      298│     ):  # type: (str, Optional[str], List[str], ArgsFormat, bool) -> None
      299│         if not fmt.has_option(name):
    → 300│             raise NoSuchOptionException(name)
      301│ 
      302│         option = fmt.get_option(name)
      303│ 
      304│         if value is False:
```

How can I use Poetry to add the latest preview (nightly) build of PyTorch?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working without `--pre` option?

Answer (score 1):

The Poetry equivalent of your `pip` command would be:

```
poetry source add --priority explicit pytorch https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

And then:

```
poetry add --source pytorch torch torchvision
```

The first command adds a new source URL for packages (by default there is only PyPI) with the `explicit` priority which means that PyPI is used if no source is specified explicitly while using `poetry add`. The second command adds `torch` and `torchvision` from the specified source.

However, I was not able to install PyTorch nightly by this mean because of dependency resolution issues.

There is a second solution, but it requires you to manually select the appropriated wheel for your architecture and environment.

First, visit https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/torch/ and find a recent wheel matching your architecture and environment. For instance, if you are using Python 3.10 on apple silicon, this would be `torch-2.1.0.dev20230417-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl`. Notice the `cp310`, `macosx` and `arm64` parts.

When you are done with this first step, repeat it for TorchVision. You can then add those dependencies with `poetry add`:

```bash
poetry add "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch-2.1.0.dev20230416-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl" "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torchvision-0.16.0.dev20230416-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl"
```

or directly in `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
torch = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch-2.1.0.dev20230416-cp310-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl"}
torchvision = {url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torchvision-0.16.0.dev20230416-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl"}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by installing minicoda for m1 arm at https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html (M1 64 bit)

Comment: Offering a step by step set of instructions that others can follow is really helpful.